# UITableView actions & passing data to main view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

In my basic flashlight app I have a main table view scene that links to two other table view scenes to set values for brightness & time. I have the transitions working but I'm wondering a few things.

1. How can I add actions to my table cells to make the selection? The CTRL+Drag technique doesn't allow actionn
2. How can I return the value select, for instance if they touch "Low" for brightness, I want that to set a value in the main controller for my app.

[My basic scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iCHa.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. For performing action on selected row, use delegate method

   ```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        //Action
   }
   ```
2. For passing the value select to mainViewController, you have to create a property in mainViewControlle. Access or assign it wherever you want by importing mainViewController.h